# D3JS Is it possible to draw Vertical set of Bubbles based on the size

Tags: d3.js, charts

D3JS Is it possible to draw Vertical set of Bubbles based on the size
I am very new to Java script framework especially visualization like D3JS. For basic chart I can get the samples from web. But these kind of manipulated charts, I dont how to create like this one. Please help.

[image]

data json:

```
[{Total: 750, left: 250, rigth: 500},
 {Total: 75, left: 25, rigth: 50}
]
```

Total: Total No of Employee

Left: Total No of Female Employee

Right: Total No of Male Employee

Comment: Thanks @rioV8 for formatted my question.

Comment: The answer is "Yes" - now please post what you have tried to that end as there is really nothing in this question to "fix" or say what you did wrong.  I do not see that your example is "based on size" please clarify what that is supposed to mean here.

Comment: Is `rigth: 500` misspelled (apparently) on purpose?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, Thanks for your response.I am very new to Java script framework especially visualization like D3JS. For basic chart I can get the samples from web. But these kind of manipulated charts, I dont how to create like this one.

Comment: The scenario is I have to group the data based the location. Here is the Total is total no of employee and left side Total No of Female and Right side: Total No of Male

Comment: Show what you have tried and we can help fix it, as it stands there is nothing for us to fix here since you posted not code attempting to do what you wish.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, some how managed to get this chart. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circles are drawn with the following snippet.

The horizontal lines and numbers are left as an exercise.

```js
var svgWidth = 700, svgHeight = 700;
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', svgWidth).attr('height', svgHeight);
var data = [
  {Total: 750, left: 250, right: 500},
  {Total: 75, left: 25, right: 50},
  {Total: 1000, left: 750, right: 250},
  {Total: 125, left: 25, right: 100}
];

var yScale = d3.scaleBand().domain(d3.range(data.length)).rangeRound([0,svgHeight]);
var radius = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,1200]).range([10, yScale.bandwidth()*0.5]);

var bars = svg.selectAll('.bar')
    .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('transform', (d,i) => `translate(${svgWidth * 0.5},${yScale(i)+yScale.bandwidth()*0.5})`)
    ;
bars.append('circle')
    .attr('r', d => radius(d.Total));
bars.append('text')
    .text( d => d.Total)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('dy', '0.3em');
```

```css
.bar circle {
  fill:none;
  stroke:steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will check and update you. Since I have to add some changes on this. for left and right bar and data display.

Comment: Somehow managed to draw this chart. do you have your gallery website?